# How to match substring without regex

Tags: mysql, substring

I know about the `LIKE` operator, but it uses regular expression, which can lead to ReDoS attacks if I am not careful and don't sanitize the user input. What I need is matching against keywords. A simple substring matching (like indexOf in countless languages) would be nice. I did some research with google, but found only solutions with `LIKE`. Does anyone know about such MySQL function or operator?

Comment: Never mind, I found it in the docs.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate